# gotoAndStop() in anonymous function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a MovieClip with an anonymous Touch Event function, and when I execute `this.gotoAndStop(2)` I get an error that says `gotoAndStop() is not a function`.  However, in a non-anonymous function, I don't get this error.

Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `this` is not what you expect it to be.

One way around `this` is this:  capture "this" into local variable and use it in function.

```
....
var me = this;
whatever.addEventListener("foo", function(v:TypeOfEvent)
{ 
   // note that this != me here 
   me.gotoAndStop();
}
```

If you do the same for member function ActionScript will automatically capture "this" and it will be "bound" properly as descripted in [ActionScript:Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html) and [Bound methods](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa5) articles:

> Methods behave similarly in that they also retain information about the lexical environment in which they were created. This characteristic is most noticeable when a method is extracted from its instance, which creates a bound method. The main difference between a function closure and a bound method is that the value of the this keyword in a bound method always refers to the instance to which it was originally attached, whereas in a function closure the value of the this keyword can change.

So following code will have expected value of `this` inside member function `memeberFunction`:

```
whatever.addEventListener("foo", memberFunction);
```

Note: ActionScript have very similar rules to JavaScript about `this` in anonymous functions, so you may find [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) question useful.

Comment: Nothing is what it seems.